# AngularJS loads constructor multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my controller is loaded multiple times in my AngularJS 1.5 code:

```
<div ng-repeat="conditionForMultipleRows"> 
 <div data-ng-if="$first">
   <div co-my-component></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
export function coMyComponent(): ng.IDirective {
  return {
    template: coMyComponentTemplateHtml,
    controller: 'MyComponentController',
    controllerAs:'$ctrl'
  }
}
```

```
export class MyComponentController{

state: MyStateClass;
static $inject = [someServices]
constructor(someServices) {
 document.getElementById("myComponent").addEventListener("myEvent", (ev: CustomEvent) => {
 doStuff()
}
```

The HTML Part is only called once, so there should be no issue. Only my controller is loaded multiple times.
The angular.module only loads the controller once and the directive only once, so there is no issue. Also there is no other place where the controller or webcomponent is called in the code.

I'm not very familiar with AngularJS so you can also point out other parts if you see something wrong here. Please refer to a source if it was resolved there. I didnt find any helpful answer

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: By loaded, do you mean that your controller's contructor is called multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. The constructor is currently called four times

Answer (score 3):

Each time your directive is instantiated, it will received a brand new controller.

The `ng-repeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection.
In your case, if `conditionForMultipleRows` is an array having four items inside, you will instantiate four times the template

```
<div data-ng-if="$first">
   <div co-my-component></div>
</div>
```

Each template instance gets its own scope and own controller, thus calling the constructor four times.

Comment: I understand and its now more clear to me. Thanks. 
But how can I resovle this, what is the best approach here? I read something about a filter and passing a function in the ng-repeat.

In my understanding the ng-if=$first only shows the first elements but loads throgh the scope created by the ng-repeat the controller multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my issue here is:

```
<div ng-repeat="conditionForMultipleRows track by $index "> 
 <div data-ng-if="$first">
   <div co-my-component></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With adding `track by $index`, the controller of my component only loaded once.
Also learned that in a ng-repeat it should always be added a "track by". There are only a few egde cases where this isnt required. Correct me if I'm wrong